# Router problems in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework2, router

I've been stuck in this problem now for 3 days and don't understand why this code is producing this error

```
 'blogPost' => array(
                'type'   => `Segment`,
                `options`=> array(
                    'route' => `/blog/post[/:postId]`,
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Rovers\Controller\Blog',
                        'action'     => 'post',
                    )
                )
            )
```

error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Missing "type" option' in C:\web\main\myZend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php on line 860

Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Missing "type" option in C:\web\main\myZend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack.php on line 269

Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException: An exception was raised while creating "Router"; no instance returned in C:\web\main\myZend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php on line 860
```

Comment: You have used backticks instead of apostrophes in couple of places here. Is it a formatting mistake?

Comment: 'may_terminate' => true,
          'blogPost' => array(
                'type'   => 'Segment',
                `options`=> array(
                    'route' => '/blog/post[/:postId]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Rovers\Controller\Blog',
                        'action'     => 'post',
                    )
                )
            )
the error still appears

Comment: i have remove the 'may_terminate'  and it works and change `` to '' thank you very much sir for your help sir for taking time on looking at my code sir :)

Answer (score 1):

When getting this error, check:

- does your configuration file contain "routes" and is it being loaded in the first place?
- you sometimes may have child routes defined but not have the main route
- do you have a 'type' in your route that is properly defined using single or double quotes ' or " and not any other similar-looking symbol